# Find frequency of vector elements in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix, vector, frequency

I have a matrix in R, here is a small example:

```
set.seed(1)
n.columns<-6
mat <- matrix(, nrow = 5, ncol = n.columns)
for(column in 1:n.columns){
  mat[, column] <- sample(1:10,5)
}
mat
```

The matrix looks like this:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    3    9    3    5   10    4
[2,]    4   10    2    7    2    1
[3,]    5    6    6    8    6   10
[4,]    7    5   10    3    1    7
[5,]    2    1    5   10    9    3
```

I also have a vector `v` of integers, `v<-c(1,3,6)`, whose elements could theoretically appear in the matrix `mat` above.

What I am looking for is an overview of the number of times that each element in `v` appears in `mat` ***per column***. For the current example this overview is

```
1: 0 1 0 0 1 1
3: 1 0 1 1 0 1
6: 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

It is fairly straightforward to do this using `for`-loops and `if`-statements, but this solution is not very pretty.

Is there a professional way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option using `sapply`:

```
t(sapply(v, function(a) colSums(mat==a)))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
#[1,]    0    1    0    0    1    1
#[2,]    1    0    1    1    0    1
#[3,]    0    1    1    0    1    0
```

Comment: You can of course set the row-names like `rownames(res) <-
 as.character(v)` where `res` is the resultant matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Using `table`:

```
table(mat[mat %in% v], col(mat)[mat %in% v])

#   1 2 3 4 5 6
# 1 0 1 0 0 1 1
# 3 1 0 1 1 0 1
# 6 0 1 1 0 1 0
```

A drawback is a column with all values not in `v` will not be reported.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sapply` on data.frame iterates over columns.

```
setNames(object = as.data.frame(sapply(v, function(a)
         sapply(as.data.frame(mat), function(b)
                             sum(a %in% b)))), nm = v)
#   1 3 6
#V1 0 1 0
#V2 1 0 1
#V3 0 1 1
#V4 0 1 0
#V5 1 0 1
#V6 1 1 0
```